# How to start Ionic 4 Lab for external access

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm running Ionic in a docker container.

When I start `ionic serve` I can access the Testserver from my host machine with `localhost:8100`.

When I start `ionic serve -l` it is not possible to access the lab from my host with `localhost:8200`

The test server outputs

```
Lab: http://localhost:8200
Local: http://localhost:8100
External: http://172.22.0.9:8100
DevApp: my_app@8100 on 520710a333bb
```

So the lab is only started on localhost, and can not be accessed from the host. How it is possible to access the Lab from the host?

Answer (score 1):

need change lab-host

```
ionic serve -l --lab-host=0.0.0.0 --lab-port=8200
```